# Limit image width or height depending on which dimension is smaller

Tags: html, css

How to set the size of `img` so that it's `max-width` is set to `200px` if the width is smaller than `height` (the image `height` is auto in this case to preserve aspect ratio), and set `max-width` to `200px` if the `width` is bigger than `height`?

Using `min-height` and `min-width` doesn't help because the image will be very large (it will have its original size).

Comment: Show your code effort .

Comment: "Width is smaller than height" is the same as "height is bigger than width". So what is the question?

Comment: wouldn't you just use `img {max-width: 200px; width: 100%; height: auto;}` This would give you the responsiveness that your require?

Comment: @Aaron No, look: if width>height, the height should be set to 200px, otherwise the width should be set to 200px.

Comment: Why not go `max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px`?

Answer (score 1):

try to this way

```
$("selector img").each(function () {
        var imgwidth = $(this).width();
        var imgheight = $(this).height();
        if (imgwidth > imgheight) {
            $(this).css('width', '100%');
            $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        }
        else if (imgwidth < imgheight) {
                $(this).css('width', 'auto');
                $(this).css('height', '100%');
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this using `css` alone. You will need javascript or jQuery.
I'm still unclear about your question.

Assuming that you want to set `height:200px` if width > height and vice versa following will work.

```
$("img").each(function () {
    var width = $(this).width();
    var height = $(this).height();

    if (width > height) {
        $(this).css('width', 'auto');
        $(this).css('height', '200px');
    }
    else if (width < height) {
            $(this).css('max-width', '200px');
            $(this).css('height', 'auto');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, you will be able to achieve this result straightforwardly using vanilla `javascript`:

```
var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
var imageWidth = image.offsetWidth;
var imageHeight = image.offsetHeight;

if (imageWidth > imageHeight) {
    image.style.height = '200px';
    image.style.width = 'auto';
    }

else if (imageHeight > imageWidth) {
    image.style.width = '200px';
    image.style.height = 'auto';
    }

}
```